# Add new button every time button is clicked and button with new color in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create a page where the user can create new button every time on click event. And i want new button with new color whenever click event fire.
Please help to complete this task in angular 6

Comment: Please share what you have coded so far

Comment: Do you want to generate buttons which will generate further buttons again on click?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a stackblitz showing you how to solve the problem, in a manner which i consider is best practice.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w2zmkh

Answer (score 0):

Keep an array for tracking the buttons you have. Initially it will have only one entry which will be shown by iteration through the array. On clicking the button append a new element into the array which will dynamically generate a new button.

**app.component.ts** :

```
// Array of buttons
buttons : {
    id    : number,
    color : string
}[] = [{ id : 0, color : 'grey' }];

// Function to add new button
addButton(){
    this.buttons.push({
        id    : this.buttons.length,
        color : '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)
    })
}
```

**app.component.html** :

```
<div *ngFor="let button of buttons">
  <button [ngStyle]="{'background-color': button.color}" (click)="addButton()">Add New</button>
</div>
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jszwmk